# System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath is null for unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I have this piece of code in my Product code.

```
string cwd = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(cwd);
```

When i try to execute this logic in UnitTest i get NullReferenceException since cwd is null.

Can someone help me on what changes should i make to my product code so that it is unit testable?

Comment: Have you found solution for this?

Comment: Nope. Haven't found a solution yet

Comment: I rebuilt my logic as well and pass this data as parameter to my method now.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to move the responsibility for getting `ApplicationPhysicalPath` off to a dedicated class, which you then provide to the class containing your Product code.

This way you can replace that dependency with a mocked equivalent when you're Unit Testing.

This approach is all part and parcel of the [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) / [Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) software engineering patterns.